# Elasticsearch: Alert on significant data change

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, business-intelligence, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index with exchange rates change log. Documents inside index look like this

```json
    {
          "sourceId": "gh-ghs",
          "targetCountry": "gh",
          "targetCurrency": "ghs",
          "rate": 2.3,
          "modified": "2021-04-07T12:00:57.2760000Z",
    },
    {
          "sourceId": "gh-ghs",
          "targetCountry": "gh",
          "targetCurrency": "ghs",
          "rate": 2.5,
          "modified": "2021-04-06T12:00:57.2760000Z",
    },
    {
          "sourceId": "mx-mxn",
          "targetCountry": "mx",
          "targetCurrency": "mxn",
          "rate": 20.3,
          "modified": "2021-04-08T12:00:57.2760000Z",
    },
    {
          "sourceId": "mx-mxn",
          "targetCountry": "mx",
          "targetCurrency": "mxn",
          "rate": 2.2,
          "modified": "2021-04-07T12:00:57.2760000Z",
    },
    {
          "sourceId": "mx-mxn",
          "targetCountry": "mx",
          "targetCurrency": "mxn",
          "rate": 2.23,
          "modified": "2021-04-06T12:00:57.2760000Z",
    }
```

As you can see we have exchange rate change per destination (country+currency). Take a look `mx-mxn` documents. Last change was from 2.2 to 20.3. Probably it is human mistake, and we want to alert about such cases.

I tried to create following query to find significant changes

```json
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [],
            {
              "range": {
                "modified": {
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
                  "gte": "now",
                  "lte": "now - 5h"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [],
          "must_not": []
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sourceId",
            "size": 1000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "2-metric": {
              "top_metrics": {
                "metrics": {
                  "field": "rate"
                },
                "size": 2,
                "sort": {
                  "modified": "desc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Using this query I managed to get to latest changes by destination. Response look like this

```json
    {
      "aggregations": {
        "group": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "mx-mxn",
              "doc_count": 25,
              "2-metric": {
                "top": [
                  {
                    "sort": [
                      "2022-10-16T15:01:57.098Z"
                    ],
                    "metrics": {
                      "rate": 12
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "sort": [
                      "2022-10-16T13:01:57.098Z"
                    ],
                    "metrics": {
                      "rate": 150
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "gh-ghs",
              "doc_count": 18,
              "2-metric": {
                "top": [
                  {
                    "sort": [
                      "2022-10-14T11:28:38.995Z"
                    ],
                    "metrics": {
                      "rate": 11.25
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "sort": [
                      "2022-10-13T11:37:09.945Z"
                    ],
                    "metrics": {
                      "rate": 10.9609375
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

So I managed to get two latest changes for each destination. But I want to setup alert for all buckets, where value changed more than on 10 percent. In this case it is mx-mxn. How can I do it in Elastic and Kibana ?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

To gather the "detection" data:

- [anomaly detection jobs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/current/ml-ad-overview.html)
- [derivative aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html)

To perform the alert:

- [Kibana alerting with machine learning job](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/master/ml-configuring-alerts.html).
- [Watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/how-watcher-works.html) with [elasticsearch query input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/input.html).

Comment: hello, but how derivative aggregation can solve my problem? It is based on histogram. And in my case date between two updates could be a week